# Приостановить таймер c#

Tags: c#

У меня есть таймер `System.Timers.Timer`,который работает в фоне. Как можно приостановить таймер?

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer();
    myTimer.Enabled = true;
    myTimer.Interval = 5000;
    myTimer.Elapsed += OnTimeout;
    myTimer.AutoReset = true;
}
```

Comment: Уточните класс используемого вами таймера

Comment: @alexey там же написано `System.Timers.Timer`

Comment: @Herrgott  когда был оставлен данный комм. этого там ещё не было написано...

Answer (score 1):

Метода именно приостанавливающего работу таймера нет. 
Метод `.Stop();` вызываемый на экземпляре вашего класса `System.Timers.Timer`  может подойти в качестве замены. Данный метод останавливает работу таймера и сбрасывает уже отсчитанное время. Т.е. если после вызова `.Stop();` вызвать `.Start();` то до события Elapsed пройдёт время равное Interval

Comment: Я уже спрашивал вас, повторюсь: Что вы имеете ввиду когда говорите "в фоне"?

Comment: Область видимости первого таймера? доступен ли он за пределами метода в котором создаётся и запускается?

Comment: @propro17 а как же тогда второй таймер будет его "приостанавливать"?

Comment: Почитайте про область видимости объектов в C#. Это основы, которые просто необходимо знать, чтобы понимать, как работает написанный вами код.

Comment: @propro17 ну тогда во втором таймере вызывайте .Stop() на нём.

Comment: @propro17 не, полагаю что так: t1.Stop();

Comment: @Alexey я обновил вопрос. Покажите тут

Comment: @propro17 в вашем случае никак. Область видимости вашего таймера- метод Main. За его пределами ссылки на таймер у вас нет, соответственно получить доступ к нему дабы остановить вы не сможете.

Comment: @propro17 myTimer.Stop() - остановит работу таймера.

Comment: @Alexey  Поможете! Если я добавлю в таблицу ещё одну строку, как поставить условие if (добавилась строка)

Comment: @Alexey поможете?